# Where in Stockholm do buses leaving for Serbia depart from?

Tags: buses, sweden, serbia, stockholm

I have a friend who is going by bus from Stockholm to Novi Pazar in Serbia, with the bus Company Benko tours 92, which runs from the Stockholm Suburbs of Täby and Huddinge.

Does anyone know exactly where in These Suburbs the Benko Tours 92 buses stop? I've tried contacting the Company but no one there speaks a word of anything but Serbian

Comment: Are you sure about that? Benko Tours 92 seems to operate a bus line from Gothenburg to Novi Pazar, but I can't find any info on buses from Stockholm. Is your friend perhaps supposed to use another bus from Täby or Huddinge to Malmö or Copenhagen and connect with the bus from Gothenburg there?

Comment: The normal bus station in Stockholm for long distance buses is [Cityterminalen](http://www.cityterminalen.com/sv/Busstrafik-och-biljetter/Utrikestrafik/). Stup Vrsac seems to be the company with departures to Belgrade.

Comment: Not the right bus

Comment: Tor-Einar: youre right. Apparently theres a phone number with a Swedish-speaking guy you can call, so I asked him and he said separate minibuses run from Uppsala (via Täby and Huddinge) to Göteborg if there are 5 people or more, then the main line connects to Novi Pazar. He was unable to give an answer regarding the stop location though...

Comment: I'll probably advise the Person in question to take Swebus from Stockholm to Jönköping and connect to the Lasta bus from there to Novi Pazar

Comment: @pnuts A search on the Website of Belgrade's bus station

Comment: @pnuts http://www.bas.rs/basweb_eng/RedVoznje.aspx?lng=en Search "Taby" and "Huddinge"

Comment: @pnuts The start station is nearby Sjenica

Comment: Did you end up finding out?

Comment: @JonathanReez Sadly not. It would indeed appear that the bas Website isn't 100% reliable, and that Neko tours 92 only runs to Göteborg. On the other hand, NBBuss is a travel agency through which you can book scheduled charter buses from Stockholm to Mitrovica in Kosovo, close to Novi Pazar

Comment: @JonathanReez Although off-topic, myself I went on a bus the other day from Pristina to Boraas, east of Göteborg. It was booked through the agency Kosova.se, which also charters buses

Comment: Can you add that info as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Benko Tours 92's [official Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/benkotours92/photos/a.1487520904906319.1073741826.1487520534906356/1487521171572959/?type=3&permPage=1), their buses only run to Gotheborg, not Stockholm. The question is therefore moot.

[image]